# BULK INSERT - Access Denied

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I am struggling with this error for some time. I have the command below:

```
-- Declare main variables
DECLARE @command VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @currentPath VARCHAR(100);
SELECT  @currentPath = '\\SERVERNAME.Domain\Temp\';
DECLARE @currentFile VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @currentDate VARCHAR(100) = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 126),'-',''),'T','T'),':','');

-- BILL OF MATERIALS
SET @currentFile = 'File'
TRUNCATE TABLE SampleData.iTable;
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
SET @command =    ' BULK INSERT SampleData.iTable'
SET @command = @command + ' FROM ''' + @currentPath + @currentFile + '.csv'''
SET @command = @command + ' WITH '
SET @command = @command + ' (FIRSTROW = 2, '
SET @command = @command + '  FIELDTERMINATOR = '';'', '
SET @command = @command + '  ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'', '
SET @command = @command + '  MAXERRORS = 99999, '
SET @command = @command + '  ERRORFILE = ''' + @currentPath + @currentFile + '_ERROR_' + @currentDate + '.csv'',' 
SET @command = @command + '  TABLOCK '
SET @command = @command + ' ) '
EXECUTE (@command)
```

It works well if I run it from Management Studio inside the SQL Server VM. If I run this bulk insert from management studio from my computer or any other computer, connected to the same SQL Server instance, with the same user, same database and everything.. I get error below:

Cannot bulk load because the file "\SERVERNAME.Domain\Temp\File.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.).

Possible reason is that user is in a different domain than the SQL Server and shared path.. but not confident this is the issue as well because I can successfully run the BULK INSERT from the SQL Server VM

Another possible reason is active directory delegation, but I don't have permission to check this and also why would it be delegation if I can run the command from the SQL VM server?

Any bit of advice is appreciated!

Thanks

Felipe Carlesso

Comment: Can you open the folder \\SERVERNAME.Domain\Temp\ from your local machine?

Comment: Yes! Just to be sure, I gave this folder full permission to Everyone

Comment: I have the same problem